# Countable disjoint collection of measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In Royden's real analysis, it is stated as a proposition that for a **finite** disjoint collection of measurable sets $\{E_k\}$, we have
$$m^*(A \cap (\cup_{i=1}^nE_i)) = \sum_{i=1}^n m^*(A\cap E_i).$$
However, what I am wondering is whether this holds also for **countable** set of disjoint collection of measurable set. I tried to prove that it is true. By monotinicity,
$$
m^*(A\cap (\cup_{i=1}^\infty E_i)) \geq \sum_{i=1}^n m^*(A\cap E_i)
$$
Take the limit, we have

$$
m^*(A\cap (\cup_{i=1}^\infty E_i)) \geq \sum_{i=1}^\infty m^*(A\cap E_i)\tag{1}
$$
On the other hand, by disjointness and countable subadditivity we get
$$
m^*(A\cap (\cup_{i=1}^\infty E_i)) \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty m^*(A\cap E_i)\tag{2}
$$
Combine equation one and two yields the equality for the countable case. However, I don't think that my reasoning correct as the countable case is never stated as a proposition in the textbook. Could someone please let me know whether this is correct or not? If not, why?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: This is correct. It's in some extensive handwritten notes I wrote in the mid 1980s, with the same proof you've given. Unfortunately, this was before I began heavily documenting where I'd seen things, so I don't have a reference. However, my recollection is that this was on a real analysis Ph.D. qualifying exam from somewhere (Indiana University?), but I'm sure I've since seen it in some texts. I looked in one that I thought I may have seen it ([Wheeden/Zygmund](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0824764994)), but it's not there. If you're really interested in a reference, I can look elsewhere.

Comment: My old typewritten measure theory notes (Paul Chernoff, ca. '84) uses something like the above to show that the collection of measurable sets induced from an outer measure is a $\sigma$ field.